# How to open dialog and pass data from BehaviorSubject?

Tags: angular

There is a users subject:

```
public users$ = new BehaviorSubject();
```

Inside component I get users as observer:

```
class Component {
   public users$: Observable<User>;
   public move() {
        if(this.users$.length) {
           this.dialog.open(DialogComponeent, {});
        }
   }
}
```

So, I need to get value from `users$` in method `move()` and pass it to dialog window. How to do that?

Comment: Given that the `users$` is a `BehaviorSubject`, you can use `this.users$.value` to get the last emitted value.

Comment: Problem is I have to duplicate code, so place `public users$: BehaviorSubject<User>;` also in component

Comment: I want to handle this using rxjs approach

Comment: How and when is `move` called? What happens if you call `move` and only after that `user$` value changes?

Comment: It is called from temaplte onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to the value of BehaviorSubject directly at this moment. Your code should be like this:

Simple way:

```
class Component {
   public users$: Observable<User>;
   public move() {
        if(this.users$.value.length) {
           this.dialog.open(DialogComponeent, {
             data: this.users$.value
           });
        }
   }
}
```

More convenient way:

```
class Component {
   public users$: Observable<User>;
   public move() {
        this.users$.pipe(
          first(),
          filter(value => value.length),
        ).subscribe(value => 
          this.dialog.open(DialogComponeent, {
             data: value
          })
        );
   }
}
```

Comment: Where to show message that lenght is zero?

Comment: What id user calls method `move()` second time, would it work?

Comment: it would work any time you call `move()` method

Comment: If you want parsing value for 0 and show error, for example you can remove `filter` pipe and check `if` statement inside subscription.